# Jackson ObjectMapper - fail on "null" as JSON string

Tags: java, jackson

Is it possible to make ObjectMapper fail when `"null"` is the entire string that is passed in?

The below code returns null, rather than throwing an exception:

`objectMapper.readValue("null", MyModel.class);`

I have tried the following configurations, with no luck:

```
.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, true)
.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, true)
.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson doesnt even try to deserialize "null" values, so the only way is to sanitize input before mapping